# How to replace a string in a text file without copying the text into new file?

Tags: c++

I am using this code which perfectly replaces the string with any string that i want to replace,but first this code copies the text file to another temporary file,i dont  want to do this i just want to replace the string in that file only is it possible? if yes, how ,give me example please??

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char *buffer = "Who";
  string search_string = buffer;
  string replace_string = "oranges";
  string inbuf;
  fstream input_file("c:\\file.txt", ios::in);
  ofstream output_file("c:\\file1.txt");

  while (!input_file.eof())
  {
      getline(input_file, inbuf);

      int spot = inbuf.find(search_string);
      if(spot >= 0)
      {
         string tmpstring = inbuf.substr(0,spot);
         tmpstring += replace_string;
         tmpstring += inbuf.substr(spot+search_string.length(), inbuf.length());
         inbuf = tmpstring;
      }

      output_file << inbuf << endl;
  }
  input_file.close();
  remove("c:\\file.txt");
  output_file.close();
  rename("c:\\file1.txt","c:\\file.txt");


}
```

Comment: Why is the code commented?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for code.

Comment: Unless the replacement has the exact same length as the original string it is better to keep the current solution.

Comment: Don't do `while (!input_file.eof())`, it will not work as you expect. The reason is that the `eofbit` flag will not be set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file. Instead do e.g. `while(std::getline(...))`.

Comment: @sashoalm just because they ask for code doesn't mean you have to give it to them. I think it's a legitimate question. Too bad it can't be done.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sorry for that, I voted entirely based on the format of the question - "My code does X, but I want it to do Y. Is it possible? If so, give me an example [code], please?? Here's my code dump." Not capitalizing sentences didn't help, either. But you're right, the question itself, once I re-read it twice, and deciphered it, and read the code, is a good one. Had it been asked in a totally  different way, I would have upvoted it for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking for is only possible if the searched string and the replacement string are the same length, or if the searched string is at the very end of the file.  Only then are you able to modify the source file directly.  Otherwise, if the two strings are different lengths, or the searched string is in the front/middle of the file, then it is simply not possible to modify the source file, you must create a separate temp file and then replace the source file when ready.

Comment: Can you provide an example?